# Non-Deterministic workflow detected while running Orchestrator

Tags: azure-durable-functions, azure-deployment-slots

When I run orchestrations, most of them fail with an exception:

The orchestrator function 'x' failed: "Failed to deserialize exception from TaskActivity: Unhandled exception while executing orchestration: DurableTask.Core.Exceptions.NonDeterministicOrchestrationException:
Non-Deterministic workflow detected:
A previous execution of this orchestration scheduled an activity task with sequence ID 0 and name 'x' (version ''),
but the current replay execution hasn't (yet?) scheduled this task. Was a change made to the orchestrator code after this instance had already started running?

at DurableTask.Core.TaskOrchestrationContext.HandleTaskScheduledEvent(TaskScheduledEvent scheduledEvent) in /*/src/DurableTask.Core/TaskOrchestrationContext.cs:line 266
at DurableTask.Core.TaskOrchestrationExecutor.g__ProcessEvents|11_0(IEnumerable`1 events) in /_/src/DurableTask.Core/TaskOrchestrationExecutor.cs:line 108 at DurableTask.Core.TaskOrchestrationExecutor.ExecuteCore(IEnumerable`1 pastEvents, IEnumerable`1 newEvents) in /_/src/DurableTask.Core/TaskOrchestrationExecutor.cs:line 119 at DurableTask.Core.TaskOrchestrationContext.HandleTaskScheduledEvent(TaskScheduledEvent scheduledEvent) in /_/src/DurableTask.Core/TaskOrchestrationContext.cs:line 266 at DurableTask.Core.TaskOrchestrationExecutor.<ExecuteCore>g__ProcessEvents|11_0(IEnumerable`1 events) in /*/src/DurableTask.Core/TaskOrchestrationExecutor.cs:line 108
at DurableTask.Core.TaskOrchestrationExecutor.ExecuteCore(IEnumerable`1 pastEvents, IEnumerable`1 newEvents) in /_/src/DurableTask.Core/TaskOrchestrationExecutor.cs:line 119". See the function execution logs for additional details.

I have added the app setting WEBSITE_ADD_SITENAME_BINDINGS_IN_APPHOST_CONFIG = 1 on all slots. That didn't help. What could be the issue?

Comment: It would be helpful if we could see the implementation of the orchestrator function. Apparently the code in the orchestrator is not deterministic. More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-code-constraints